# Is there a way to hide a schema or at least the aspnet procedures from Sql Server Management Studio's proc list?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, ssms

I think the question speaks for itself, but I'm sick of scrolling through my procedure list filled with 50 aspnet procedures.

Is there a way to hide the dbo schema, or these procedures from the list?

Is there a different/equivalent tool that would let me do this?

With TOAD, I could open each schema independently - that'd be wonderful!

My only other option is to connect our membership provider to a different database instead of the same as everything else.  All in all this isn't a huge deal, but I figured I'd ask instead of being silently frustrated any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS 2005 or 2008, right click on "Stored Procedures", then on "Filter Settings", then for the "Schema" change "Operator" to "Does not contain" and then set a Value to filter them...

Comment: Wow, awesome, thanks!  Can't believe that I've been annoyed by this for so long and never figured that out.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL 2008 there is a way. It may also be in 2005. If you right-click on your Stored Procedures folder in SSMS Object Explorer, you will see a menu option named Filter. You can create a filter that only displays the stored procs you want to see. You can filter on Name, Schema, Owner and Creation Date

Comment: KM was first so I gave him the answer, but you're absolutely right.  And it IS in 2005.  Thanks so much.